# Why is the solution of (NH4)2[Ce(NO3)6] used as an oxidizing agent?

Tags: coordination-compounds

In an MCQ, the correct statement regarding the abovementioned compound is that its solution is used as an oxidizing agent.
I do not understand why that is so.

Comment: calculate the oxidation state of Ce in the compound.

Comment: I think it's +4. Which means it has achieved Xe configuration.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Most lanthanides display stability in their +3 oxidation states. Cerium does the same, which is why it has a very high reduction potential. The reduction potential for the $\ce{Ce^{4+}|Ce^{3+}}$ couple is 1.61 V (for comparison, $\ce{Cl2}$ has a potential of 1.32 V)

Cerium in the form of [ceric ammonium nitrate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ceric_ammonium_nitrate) is also quite stable compared to other oxidizing agents and can be stored on the shelf for a longish period of time. It's also quite usable: the bright orange colour is decolourized to a pale yellow on reduction of $\ce{Ce^{4+}}$. This is why it's used as a common oxidizing agent.