# Electrophilic Substitution with Ceric Ammonium Nitrate and Lithium Bromide as reagents

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, reference-request, electrophilic-substitution

The 2020 IChO Preparatory Problem List (source [here](https://icho2020.tubitak.gov.tr/storage/preparation%20problems/IChO%202020%20Preperatory%20Problems%20&%20Solutions.pdf)) had the following reaction as part of the solution to the first question:

[image: Bromination of 2-isopropyl anisole]

(CAN = Ceric Ammonium Nitrate).

**What is the mechanism for this 'Electrophilic Substitution' of the ring**? I have not encountered such a reaction before. As far as I'm aware, CAN is an oxidizing agent, whereas Lithium Bromide would dissociate to give $\ce{Br-}$, which is not an electrophile. Aromatic Nucleophilic Substitution (ArSN) is out of the question here, as the ring is highly activated by the methoxy group.

The only probable reaction I can think of is that CAN successively oxidizes $\ce{Br-}$ to $\ce{Br2}$, then to $\ce{Br+}$, but this seems unlikely, and I could not find such a reaction mentioned anywhere in literature. A mechanism for this reaction, preferably along with a reference, would be much appreciated.

Comment: Is CAN and KBr a good enough similarity?

Comment: https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/119795/10/10_chapter%204.pdf The reaction is present with a yield of 90% Page 24

Comment: I'm inclined to think that it is more likely that CAN is oxidising the aromatic to a radical cation intermediate that is then captured by Br-. If you have access (I do not) this review may cast some light https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/cr068408n

Comment: @Waylander: I think OP's suggestion is correct. This is similar to iodination of salicylamide in the presence of $\ce{NaI/NaOCl}$ (https://doi.org/10.1021/ed085p1426).

Comment: You are correct as the answer below demonstrates

Comment: @Waylander I wrote the answer btw :) Also, thanks for the reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, the linked paper clearly points out the following:

> Hint: In second step (**A** $\rightarrow$ **B**), combination of lithium bromide and cerium(IV) ammonium nitrate (CAN) is used as a brominating reagent

From a problem solving perspective, this step is trivial for someone who has read the problem well (not me, unfortunately :)

---

Ceric Ammonium Nitrate is a [very strong oxidizing agent](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/124115/why-is-the-solution-of-nh42ceno36-used-as-an-oxidizing-agent/124124#124124) and has the ability of oxidizing benzene compounds first to Nitrobenzene, then to quinone or quinoid derivatives<sup>1</sup>. Assuming this line of reasoning works, the quinoid derivative could then undergo nucleophilic addition with $\ce{LiBr}$, followed by workup with acid to give the p-subsituted benzene derivative. This could be a probable reaction mechanism, if the substitutent was $\ce{-OH}$ instead of $\ce{-OMe}$ and if an acid workup step was involved. Also, this mechanism can give the unwanted product 4-bromo-3-isopropylphenol, as shown below:

[image: Possible reaction mechanism]

However, this reaction mechanism is very speculative, and it also won't hold good here, because the substituent is $\ce{-OMe}$. Some further research on the links provided in the comments<sup>2</sup> yielded the following results:

> Alkyl aromatics were brominated in the side chain using sodium bromide and CAN. Asakura et al. reported bromination of C-5 of uracil nucleosides using CAN and lithium bromide in acetonitrile.

This is also the reaction present in ([3](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/119795/10/10_chapter%204.pdf)), which seems to have been lifted without a citation to Asakura et al.

> [image: Linked reaction in reference]

Finally, Asakura et al. <sup>4</sup> provides a suitable mechanism for this reaction, which I correctly assumed arose from the oxidation of $\ce{Br-}$ to $\ce{Br2}$, and then to $\ce{Br+}$

> [image: I'm a geeenius! Yayyyy!!!]

**References**:

1. Nikishin, G. I., et al. “Reaction of Aromatic Hydrocarbons with Cerium Ammonium Nitrate.” Bulletin of the Academy of Sciences of the USSR Division of Chemical Science, vol. 24, no. 6, **June 1975**, *pp. 1328–29*. doi:[10.1007/BF00922077](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF00922077).
2. Nair, Vijay, and Ani Deepthi. “Cerium(IV) Ammonium NitrateA Versatile Single-Electron Oxidant.” Chemical Reviews, vol. 107, no. 5, **May 2007**, *pp. 1862–91*. doi:[10.1021/cr068408n](https://doi.org/10.1021/cr068408n).
3. Cerium (IV) Ammonium Nitrate mediated oxidative transformations of diaryl methylenecyclopropanes. [Shodhganga link](https://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/bitstream/10603/119795/10/10_chapter%204.pdf)
4. Asakura, Junichi, and Morris J. Robins. “Cerium(IV)-Mediated Halogenation at C-5 of Uracil Derivatives.” The Journal of Organic Chemistry, vol. 55, no. 16, **Aug. 1990**, *pp. 4928–33*. doi:[10.1021/jo00303a033](https://doi.org/10.1021/jo00303a033).